# Yamaha Nmax what causes excessive scooter seat vibration?

Tags: motorcycle, suspension, vibration, shock-absorber, motor-mounts

I have an app that records motorcycle seat vibration and shock. While doing a test run on Yamaha NMax I have observed shock readings from the seat that are inconsistent with the ride quality. The bike seems to ride smoother than the readings suggest.

*What would be causing the bike seat to shake/vibrate at +/-1g acceleration?* or is it under dampened suspension oscillating?

I suspect worn out engine mounts or thin seat cushioning. What else could be causing seat vibration while riding?

[image: excessive seat vibration]

Here’s what smooth readings should look like:
[image]

Comment: what are the vibration when you only rev the engine and what are the vibration when you drive.

Comment: Have you checked all those mountings - be a good first step.